# how can get index & count in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have [code like this (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/badvz/b12tucho/2/)

```
  <li v-for="(itemObjKey, catalog) in catalogs">this index : {{itemObjKey}}</li>
```

**Output**:
this index: 0
this index: 1

**My question is**:

1. How can I get value index first begin: 1 for example
    I want
   output like this:
    this index: 1
    this index: 2
2. How can I get count from index, i.e. output like this:
    this index: 1
    this index: 2
    this count: 2 field

Comment: Simple remark: I would simply use the `$index`, seems cleaner. `<li v-for="item in catalogs">this index : {{$index}}</li>`

Comment: For anyone else looking at this question, the above comment would only apply to Vue 1. Vue 2 has dropped the `$index` syntax in favour of explicitly declaring the index.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you can just add 1

```
<li v-for="(catalog, itemObjKey) in catalogs">this index : {{itemObjKey + 1}}</li>
```

to get the length of an array/objects

```
{{ catalogs.length }}
```

Comment: Has the spec changed? It appears that is now (catalog, itemObjKey)... we should probably update this.

Comment: @Jonah It has: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object Was wondering why my "index/key" was an Object and "value" was a number!

Comment: This works for a v-for over an array, not an object.
For an object, use `v-for="(item, key, index) in object"`. See answer by **nsv**.

Answer (score 47):

In case, your data is in the following structure, you get string as an index

```
items = {
   am:"Amharic",
   ar:"Arabic",
   az:"Azerbaijani",
   ba:"Bashkir",
   be:"Belarusian"
}
```

In this case, you can use extra variable to get the index in number:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item, key, index) in items">
    {{ item }} - {{ key }} - {{ index }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Source: https://alligator.io/vuejs/iterating-v-for/

Comment: This answer should be way closer to the top!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. This should be the acceptable answer. Thanks!

Comment: This seems right, but it doesn't work on mine

Answer (score 19):

Alternatively, you can just use,

```
<li v-for="catalog, key in catalogs">this is index {{++key}}</li>
```

This is working just fine.

Comment: (catalog, key) must be wrapped in parentheses though

Comment: I would recommend using index instead of key because the key isn't always a number. @deathemperor it doesn't have to be wrapped to work.

Answer (score 9):

The optional SECOND argument is the index, starting at 0. So to output the index and total length of an array called 'some_list':

```
<div>Total Length: {{some_list.length}}</div>
<div v-for="(each, i) in some_list">
  {{i + 1}} : {{each}}
</div>
```

If instead of a list, you were looping through an object, then the second argument is key of the key/value pair. So for the object 'my_object':

```
var an_id = new Vue({
  el: '#an_id',
  data: {
    my_object: {
        one: 'valueA',
        two: 'valueB'
    }
  }
})
```

The following would print out the key : value pairs. (you can name 'each' and 'i' whatever you want)

```
<div id="an_id">
  <span v-for="(each, i) in my_object">
    {{i}} : {{each}}<br/>
  </span>
</div>
```

For more info on Vue list rendering: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 2):

Using Vue 1.x, use the special variable `$index` like so:

```
<li v-for="catalog in catalogs">this index : {{$index + 1}}</li>
```

alternatively, you can specify an alias as a **first argument** for `v-for` directive like so:

```
<li v-for="(itemObjKey, catalog) in catalogs">
    this index : {{itemObjKey + 1}}
</li>
```

See : [Vue 1.x guide](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/list.html)

Using Vue 2.x, `v-for` provides a **second optional argument** referencing the index of the current item, you can add 1 to it in your mustache template as seen before:

```
<li v-for="(catalog, itemObjKey) in catalogs">
    this index : {{itemObjKey + 1}}
</li>
```

See: [Vue 2.x guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for)

Eliminating the parentheses in the `v-for` syntax also works fine hence:

```
<li v-for="catalog, itemObjKey in catalogs">
    this index : {{itemObjKey + 1}}
</li>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Why its printing 0,1,2...?

Because those are indexes of the items in array, and index always starts from 0 to array.length-1.

To print the item count instead of index, use `index+1`. Like this:

```
<li v-for="(catalog, index) in catalogs">this index : {{index + 1}}</li>
```

And to show the total count use `array.length`, Like this:

```
<p>Total Count: {{ catalogs.length }}</p>
```

As per **[DOC](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for)**:

> v-for also supports an optional **second argument** (not first) for
> the index of the current item.

Answer (score 0):

this might be a dirty code but i think it can suffice

```
<div v-for="(counter in counters">
{{ counter }}) {{ userlist[counter-1].name }}
</div>
```

on your script add this one

```
data(){return {userlist: [],user_id: '',counters: 0,edit: false,}},
```